# How to add arrow to div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create error label for div with arrow, but have problem with centering.

I get: [image]

I need something like: [image]

HTML:

```
<div class="error-label-arrow"></div>
<div class="error-label">This field is required.</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.error-label{
    padding: 7px 10px 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #DA362A;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div.error-label-arrow{
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid #DA362A;
    float: left;
}
```

Is it possible?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harismvec/4rBYy/)

Comment: Add some padding? Or add a fiddle and I'll show you what I mean

Comment: You can use background image instead of creating the arrow with CSS, then give fixed height to the div and `vertical-align: center;` should work. It will also work in older browsers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [CSS Pseudo classes](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/) to do this, therefore you won't need an "arrow" element:

```css
div.error-label {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #DA362A;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 190px;
  margin: 30px;
}

div.error-label:before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  left: 18px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #DA362A;
}
```

```html
<div class="error-label">This field is required.</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to remove `margin:30px;` because it produces a lot of blank space in the area around.

Comment: @Kirix I only applied `margin` so that you'd be able to see the arrow on the screen. Note: Changes to padding/margin will require changes to `left` on the pseudo class

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution

```css
div.error-label{
    padding: 7px 10px 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #DA362A;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

div.error-label-arrow{
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid #DA362A;
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="error-label-arrow"></div>
<div class="error-label">This field is required.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can achieve this by using `Pseudo elements` check below answer

```css
.error{
   position: relative;
   background: red;
   padding: 10px;
   color: #fff;
   margin:0 0 0 12px;
   width:auto;
   display:inline-block;
 
 }

.error::before {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 9px 11px 9px 0;
 border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
 position: absolute;
 left: -11px;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
}

.arrow_type2 {
 position: relative;
 background: #28d57f;
 border: 3px solid #0cf5a7;
  padding:50px 20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
.arrow_type2:after, .arrow_type2:before {
 right: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_type2:after {
 border-color: rgba(40, 213, 127, 0);
 border-right-color: #28d57f;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
.arrow_type2:before {
 border-color: rgba(12, 245, 167, 0);
 border-right-color: #0cf5a7;
 border-width: 14px;
 margin-top: -14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">This is field required</div>


<div class="arrow_type2">Arrow type two</div>
```